# What is the Easiest Way to Join Multiple Audio Files in Windows?

Tags: audio, audio-recording

I used to have a program that did this quite well in OSX, but I haven't found any Windows alternative to joining multiple audio files into one larger audio file. The ones I've encountered so far are the type that you download and then don't really work until you pay a certain fee.

I'm working mostly with M4A files, but I can convert them to MP3's if necessary.

Thanks.

Comment: I use [Audacity](http://audacityteam.org/) for any audio work. It's free and open source.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.freemake.com/free_audio_converter/

Let's you take multiple audio files, convert them and/or join them. Supports all formats I've run into. Free.